# Cannot resolve symbol 'Dte' with envdte reference

Tags: c#, envdte

i try to detect debugger and i get error "Cannot resolve symbol 'Dte'" even with envdte reference. Google give me nothing. Thank you.

```
using EnvDTE;
namespace test
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            foreach (EnvDTE.Process p in Dte.Debugger.DebuggedProcesses) {
                if (p.ProcessID == spawnedProcess.Id) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you write this code? Where did you define Dte?

Comment: You havn't defined Dte. You should define `DTE Dte;` then assign the value to it, then use.

Comment: I copy full code here

Comment: a console application for working with dte? What do you want to do?

Comment: I need to detect is debugger(like Ollydbg) is attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to detect is debugger (like Ollydbg) attached

To check if the process has a debugger attached to yo can use:

- [**CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679280(VS.85).aspx)
- [**Debugger.IsAttached**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached(v=vs.110).aspx)

**How to check if debugger is attached**

- **CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent**    works for any running process and detects native debuggers too.
- **Debugger.IsAttached**    works only for the current process and detects only managed debuggers. As an example, **OllyDbg won't be detected by this**.

**[Code:](http://www.codingvision.net/security/c-detect-if-debugger-is-attached)**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class DetectDebugger
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern bool CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(IntPtr hProcess, ref bool isDebuggerPresent);

    public static void Main()
    {
        bool isDebuggerPresent = false;
        CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, ref isDebuggerPresent);

        Console.WriteLine("Debugger Attached: " + isDebuggerPresent);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# is a case sensitive language.

Its `DTE` (in upper case) not `Dte`.  Documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.dte.aspx